# OPLON LBL ADC: How can I setup "sticky session" for a virtual domain?

Tags: http, load-balancing, impala

I need to balance `HTTP` `requests` among a bunch of endpoints

and I need to be sure that subsequent requests from the same user (browser) are forwarded to the same endpoint.

**How can I achieve this result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sticky session in HTTP/S is the default on LBL. No actions required!

The session is injected on the response with the LBLSESSIONID cookie.

You can edit or create different session names if you want to anonymize the session name for security reasons.

On ADC Setting->ADCs->choose the ADC in the list (edit params)->Session Managers
[image: ADC edit params]